# Ruby on Rails - How to get changed object in after_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm creating action tracking for users in Ruby on Rails 3. And I want to have `after_filter` method in controllers, but I don't know how to get current object or current action in my `action_tracking` method. Any solution?

```
# some_controller.rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :action_tracking, only: [ :create, :update, :delete ]
  ...
end

# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def action_tracking
    action = <get name of action>   # create, update or delete...
    <object> = <get changed object> # event, user...
    changes = <object>.changes      # { 'title' => ["Title", "New Title"] }
    <object>.tracking.create(action, changes)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def action_tracking
  action = params[:action]
  changes = changed_object.changes
  changed_object.tracking.create(action, changes)
end

# override for each controller
# there is no way to know this in a generic way, unless you use something
# like inherited_resources, or active scaffold, where the objects is "known"
def changed_object
  @user
end
```

Comment: Thx, it works, but value `changes` is always empty. Is it because I call it after save (on save `changes` resets). Is it possible fix without adding more code to `some_controller` action?

Comment: Yes that is right, on save `changes` resets. I'd say the best way to do this (and I did this sort of thing before) is to put the logic in the model in either a callback or an observer, and pass the action name along. In such a context (callback or observer) the changes hash is not yet reset.

Comment: I tried to add tracking to the model, but model don't have access to some variables (like `params[]`..), which I need. And I don't know what you mean (callback or observer), can you post some link to an article about it?

Comment: [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) [observers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers)

Comment: Might want to check [acts_as_autited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited) The variables you can "pass in" via various methods - set an accessor and pick up later, Thread.local[:var] etc